# Drawing a snowflake using recursion

Tags: python, recursion, turtle-graphics, fractals

I want to create an output like this: ￼￼

[image]

I have to use recursion.

So far , This is what my code looks like:

```
from turtle import *


    def drawFlake(length,depth):
    
        fd(length)
        input("first line done")
        if depth>0:
    
    
            left(60)
            drawFlake(length/3,depth-1)
    
            input("1")
            left(120)
            drawFlake(length/3,depth-1)
            input("2")
    
            left(120)
            drawFlake(length/3,depth-1)
            input("3")
    
            left(120)
            drawFlake(length/3,depth-1)
            input("4")
    
            left(120)
            left(180)
            #drawFlake(length/3,depth-1)
            input("1")
    
            left(120)
            drawFlake(length/3,depth-1)
    
            input("THIS IS THE LAST")
            left(60)
    
    
    
        left(180)
        fd(length)


drawFlake(100,3)
```

And this produces an output like this(here, N =3)

The issue is that long line at the left. There should be no long line. Instead, there should be another flake pattern

What Am I doing wrong ?

[image]

EDIT::

This is something better that I managed to come up with. But it is still not perfect :

```
def doFigure(length,depth):

        left(120)
        fd(length)
        if depth>1:
         doFigure(length/3,depth-1)

        bk(length)
        right(60)

        fd(length)
        if depth>1:
         doFigure(length/3,depth-1)
        bk(length)
        right(60)

        fd(length)
        if depth>1:
         doFigure(length/3,depth-1)
        bk(length)
        right(60)

        fd(length)
        if depth>1:
         doFigure(length/3,depth-1)
        bk(length)
        right(60)

        fd(length)
        if depth>1:
         doFigure(length/3,depth-1)
        bk(length)
        right(60)

        fd(length)
        if depth == 3:

            doFigure(length/3,depth-1)
        bk(length)
        right(180)
```

[image]

Note the 5th last line. I am having to hard code the value 3 to get the correct value.

Comment: what is `doTest()` , is it same as `drawFlake()` ?

Comment: yes, sorry, my mistake. It is supposed to be drawFlake()

Comment: And your issue is that it looks very small?

Comment: no, issue is that long line at the left. There should be no long line. Instead, there should be another flake pattern

Comment: I proposed a new answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days , I came up with a solution. This is definitely not the best way to go about it(I would be glad if more people posted their solutions), but It does show the output EXACTLY like in my original picture.

```
def makeFlake(length,depth,isRoot=True):
    """
    This function draws the flakes. To draw the smaller flakes, this function is called recursively
    :param length: the length of the biggest flake's branch
    :param depth: The number of smaller flakes to draw
    :param isRoot: Draw an extra branch if the value is true. Note that true is the default value. 
    """
    if depth>0:
        forward(length)
        makeFlake(length // 3, depth - 1,False)
        backward(length)
        left(60)

        forward(length)
        makeFlake(length // 3, depth - 1,False)
        backward(length)
        left(60)

        forward(length)
        makeFlake(length // 3, depth - 1,False)
        backward(length)
        left(60)

        forward(length)
        if isRoot == True:
         makeFlake(length // 3, depth - 1,False)
        backward(length)
        left(60)

        forward(length)
        makeFlake(length // 3, depth - 1,False)
        backward(length)
        left(60)

        forward(length)
        makeFlake(length // 3, depth - 1,False)
        backward(length)
        left(60)
```

Comment: Either `if isRoot:`, or if you must, `if isRoot is True:` but never `if isRoot == True:`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution: it is not perfect as it has an extra bunch along the main stems compared to the drawing you posted.

Let me know if that works for you.

from turtle import *

```
def drawFlake(length, depth):
    "draws a flake"
    if depth > 0:
        for _ in range(6):
            forward(length)
            drawFlake(length // 3, depth - 1)
            backward(length)
            left(60)

drawFlake(200,4)
```

[image: Flake depth 4]

Comment: I have to use the value 3 anyway. Also, the output is totally messed up. I don't think its close to the correct

Comment: Post your entire code if you like, so I can test it.

Comment: I have done so. There might be an indentation error though

Answer (score 1):

If you want to draw it exactly as pictured, you have to skip every 4th innermost snowflake out of the 6 spokes (i.e skipping every '3' in a loop from 0 to 5)

Here's a code for that

```
import turtle as t

#assigning random value for outer at the start, this will be changed later
OUTER=-1
LEN=300
def drawSnowflake(N,LEN):
    if N<0:
        return
    for i in range(6):
        t.forward(LEN)
        #skipping every 4th spoke but not for the level N
        if i==3 and N!=OUTER:
            pass
        else:
            drawSnowflake(N-1,LEN/4)
        t.backward(LEN)
        t.left(60)



def main():
    N=int(input("Enter a max value of N"))
    global OUTER
    OUTER=N
    t.speed(0)
    drawSnowflake(N,LEN)
    t.exitonclick()


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the solution by @amipro (+1) except that it overdraws existing lines (slight inefficiency, look carefully.)  And I also prefer the way you flagged the root exeption in your own solution (+1).  So, here's my own solution which I hope reflects the best of both:

```
from turtle import *

def makeFlake(length, depth, isRoot=True):

    if depth > 0:
        for branch in range(6):
            if isRoot or branch != 3:
                forward(length)
                makeFlake(length / 3, depth - 1, False)
                backward(length)

            left(60)

tracer(False)  # because I have no patience
makeFlake(100, 4)
tracer(True)

hideturtle()

exitonclick()
```

[image]